# What command should I use to get the actual value of a parameter in Toad for Oracle?

Tags: oracle, toad

I'm trying to get the actual value of [OPTIMIZER_SECURE_VIEW_MERGING](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams146.htm) in Toad for Oracle but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
from v$parameter
where upper(name) = 'OPTIMIZER_SECURE_VIEW_MERGING'
```

See Oracle doc for details on [v$parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_2085.htm) 
Your login would need read access to the v$parameter view.  FYI, there is no dependency on TOAD for this - just a straight SQL query, can be run from any SQL client.

I am running TOAD 12, and you can also view all the current oracle parameters from the Database/Administer/Oracle Parameters menu item.

Comment: Adding to this, To find all metadata tables/views with its description use "select * from dictionary".